# How do I use a Taxonomy in a CCK created field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

In Drupal 6. Using CCK I am creating a custom content type. And in this content type I create fields. Now one field is called location and it has a dropdown where you can select the location from a prepopulated list. I want these items to be a taxonomy for sorting purposes. how do I make them a taxonomy cause as of right now they are simple prepopulated text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to use the [Content Taxonomy module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy). Then just create the vocabulary and add a field of this type to your content type, linking it to that vocabulary.